# Trying to swap between 3 images on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 different info-check classes with each a different span that should show a different image. When I hover info-check, the image should be shown instead of the original image "autoselect-pic". And when mouseout, the image should change back to the original "autoselect-pic". I tried using jquery for this, but I could'nt find the correct way to do this. This is my HTML and CSS:

```css
div.info-check { 
  position: absolute; 
  right: 50px; 
  top: 2px; 
  background-size: 100%; 
  width: 15px; 
  height: 15px; }

span.breedte-tooltip, span.hoogte-tooltip, span.inch-tooltip {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 230px;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 20; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease; }

span.breedte-tooltip { background-image: url('/images/icons/breedte-bepalen.png');}
span.hoogte-tooltip { background-image: url('/images/icons/hoogte-bepalen.png'); }
span.inch-tooltip { background-image: url('/images/icons/inchmaat-bepalen.png'); }
```

```html
<div class="autoselect">
  <img class="autoselect-pic" src="/images/products/inchmaat-bepalen.png" alt="inchmaat-bepalen">
  <div class="autorow">
    <div class="breedte">
      <label for="Breedte">Breedte</label>
      <div class="info-check"><span class="breedte-tooltip"></span></div>
      <select name="Breedte" id="filter-width">
        <option>Selecteer</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="lengte">
      <label for="Hoogte">Hoogte</label>
      <div class="info-check"><span class="hoogte-tooltip"></span></div>
      <select name="lengte" id="filter-height">
        <option>Selecteer</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inch">
      <label for="Inch">Inchmaat</label>
      <div class="info-check"><span class="inch-tooltip"></span></div>
      <select name="inch" id="filter-inch">
        <option>Selecteer</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try to use the :hover selector?

Comment: With the hover selector, you cannot manipulate an existing image somewhere else in the html to change to another image as far as I know

Comment: @Larsmanson you can when you hover over a parent of the element to be affected, eg `.info-check:hover span.breedte-tooltip`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's hover function on the element you need. This is the way:

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

In the selector you put info-check, and then inside the handlers you ask it to change the images as needed. Maybe using attribute to change the source or change the class of the element(which I think is better).

For more info about [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).